# Errno 11004 getaddrinfofialed using urllib2 but not httplib

Tags: python, urllib2, google-scholar

I am new to python and am trying to build a Google Scholar **scraper** using scholar.py and TOR. Unfortunately, when I run the code below:

```
import scholar
import csv
import socks
import socket
import urllib2
import urllib
import httplib
from TorCtl import TorCtl

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1.8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)

def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050, True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    print "Connected to Tor"
    
def newId():
    socks.setdefaultproxy()
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="123")
    TorCtl.Connection.send_signal(conn, "NEWNYM")
    conn.close()
    connectTor()

connectTor()

for i in range(0, 10):
    print "case "+str(i+1)
    newId()
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.heroku.com")
    conn.request("GET", "/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.read())
```

Everything is fine and the IP address is returned. However if I drop:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("my-ip.heroku.com")
conn.request("GET", "/")
response = conn.getresponse()
print(response.read())
```

and replace it with

```
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print(urllib2.urlopen("http://my-ip.heroku.com/").read())
```

then I get the error message: "URLError urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed."

scholar.py uses urllib2 so I need it to work. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, scraping webpages via Tor isn't a good idea. You're using up bandwidth that could be used by people who actually need Tor. Plus, there are only like 1,000 exit nodes, so you don't have many unique IP addresses anyways.

Comment: @Blender Thanks I'll try another route.